# How to use product name in #import statement xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

When we want to use swift module in obj c we import product name - swift.h file. e.g if product name is "test" then we use

## import "test-swift.h"

instead of this hard coded product name, how we can use

## import ${product-name}-swift.h